# how can source files see other files without path in a cmake project?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

In a CMAKE project I have created 2 folders, a and b, each of which has `include` and src directories:

> -- MyProject
>
> CMakeLists.txt
>
> ---- a
>
> ------ include
>
> -------- a.h
>
> ---- b
>
> ------ include
>
> -------- b.h

...

`a.h` includes `b.h`. But only if the path is specified, ie, `#include "../../b/include/b.h"`.

How can I configure **cmake** so that all project files can see each other without specifying the path? eg: `#include "b.h"`

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/include_directories.html) and [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_include_directories.html)

Comment: @JanHudec I dont know why but target_include_directories is not available for me: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (target_include_directories):
  Unknown CMake command "target_include_directories"

Comment: `target_include_directories` is relatively new command. Upgrade your CMake or resort to the simple `include_directories`.

Comment: @JanHudec I had tried include_directories before and it hadn't work. But now, I don't know what mistake I did before, but yes it worked. Don't you think to write this so that I can accept? Thanks.